# Bundle and putExtra

Tags: java, android

I am new learner

When I copy a practicing code from a book I bought, it tells me that putExtra is not
defined for Bundle

Can I use putLong instead? or what?

```
public class ReminderEditActivity extends FragmentActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
    setContentView (R.layout.reminder_edit_activity);
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(ReminderEditFragment.DEFAULT_EDIT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    if (fragment == null) {
    fragment = new ReminderEditFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putExtra(ReminderProvider.COLUMN_ROWID, getIntent().getLongExtra(ReminderProvider.COLUMN_ROWID, 0L));
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager ().beginTransaction();
    transaction.add (R.id.edit_container, fragment, ReminderEditFragment.DEFAULT_EDIT_FRAGMENT_TAG);
    transaction.commit();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: `putExtra()` is a method on `Intent`

Comment: yes I know that but I want to find the best alternative method to correct the error

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can try the putLong method, Bundle don't have putExtra(). 
putLong(String key, long value)
- inserts a long value into the mapping of this Bundle, replacing any existing value for the given key.
Check this to see all Bundle methods:
[Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html)

Comment: yes I saw it. but I dont know if putlong is the best alternative

Comment: yes, i think it is if you need to use Bundle :)